# Continuity of the following complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

I am working through the text Complex Analysis by George Cain and I have a question stemming from the problem #9 in section 2.2.

Consider the function $f(z)$ given by $\frac{\overline{z}^2}{z}$ when $z\neq 0$ and $0$ when $z=0$. Is this function continuous at $z=0$?

I have found that the limit of $\frac{\overline{z}^2}{z}$ as $z$ approaches $0$ is $0$ as you approach along the $x$-axis, $y$-axis, and the line $x=y$, but I am having trouble making a general proof. Wolfram says the function is not continuous so I would appreciate it if someone could show a case where the limit of $\frac{\overline{z}^2}{z}$ as $z$ approaches $0$ is not $0$. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x,y$ be the real and imaginary parts of $z$.
$$
\left| \frac{\bar z^2} z \right| = \frac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \to 0 \text{ as }z\to 0.
$$
If $|f|\to0$ then $f\to0$.  An $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof of that is easy: to show $f\to0$ you only need to show $|f-0|<\varepsilon$ for small enough $\delta$, but $|f-0| = |f| = |f|-0 = ||f|-0|$, and you know you can make that $<\varepsilon$ by making $\delta$ small enough.

Comment: Thanks! Cool trick with the modulus. Much appreciated.